# compile error in base/cpu.cc:71:4 with Cobalt

Tags: cobalt

It said "impossible constraint in 'asm' error in base/cpu.cc:71:4, when compiled with Cobalt, after check the fluent, I found it may need to set the CPU ARCH, but I didn't not know where to set it, can anyone help me?
[The details error info is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz4rq.png)

Comment: if you have inline asm, that is pretty processor specific, is there a "configure" script that you need to run?

Comment: As you said, it did have config for the asm code, and the config platform is not right.

Comment: @petter, I strongly recommend you to consider every constant in configuration_public.h before trying to compile the code. And once it compiles, please compile and run `nplb` target to detect possible configuration errors. See https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/starboard/nplb

Comment: @mmotorny, thank you for your kind suggestion, I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the CPU ARCH in starboard/linux/x64x11/configuration_public.h(https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/e9b4b99dab6e774b8b6e63add74c352cc5dd395a/src/starboard/linux/x64x11/configuration_public.h)， if you compile Cobalt on ARM ，then you can set it as follows:

```
// Whether the current platform is an ARM architecture.
#define SB_IS_ARCH_ARM 1

// Whether the current platform is an x86 architecture.
#define SB_IS_ARCH_X86 0
```

Comment: I found it, and follow your suggestion, it works, thanks so much for your kind help!